# Traducción de "Deal with it"

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos, expresiones

¿Cuáles serían las traducciones para la expresión *Deal with it*? También pregunto traducciones que sean coloquiales, propias de cada país.

Comment: Te toca lidiar con eso

Comment: `Manejate` funciona en partes de Argentina

Answer (score 16):

Yo usaría

> Aguántate. Te aguantas.

La que mejor creo que se adapta es:

> Vive con ello.

o también puedes probar

> Supéralo.

(no en el sentido de *hazlo mejor*, si no *sobreponte*).

Comment: +1 for supéralo. It's the one we use.

Answer (score 11):

Todas las respuestas (y está también) son similares, añado tres:

Dos extraídas de [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=deal%20with%20it):

- Acéptalo.
- [Apechuga](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=apechuga)

Para casos como *If you don't like it deal with it* sería:

> ***ajo y agua*** **loc. col. Expr.** que se usa para indicar resignación:
>   *tengo que estudiar y no puedo salir, así que ajo y agua.*
>
> - Por apócope eufemística de ***a jo**derse **y agua**ntarse*.

En todas depende del contexto ya que también se podría usar *cargar con el muerto* o *pagar los platos rotos*.

Comment: Edito para facilitar, a los que lo necesiten, ver la parte de la frase origen de la expresión.

Answer (score 7):

En Argentina se dice

> Bancatelá

O también

> Manejalo

Comment: ¿Proviene de un verbo?

Comment: @David creo que debe ser «bancátela» (con *vos*) o «báncatela» (con *tú*) del verbo *bancar* que en este caso significa «Responsabilizarse, hacerse cargo de una situación» (DRAE *bancar 4.*)

Comment: @guifa es la primera, pero verbalmente se acentúa por costumbre como dijo Pablo.

Answer (score 4):

Más bien coloquial

> Apáñate

o

> Apáñate con esto

Comment: Yo estaba pensando en incluir esta forma también, pero cambié de opinión porque es un poco más como "make do". _Apáñatelas_ es algo que le dirías a alguien que quieres que haga algo sin molestarte, no algo que dices como respuesta cuando alguien te dice que no le gusta algo (en mi humilde opinión).

Answer (score 3):

Ya que la pregunta no nos da ningún contexto, propongo otra forma de traducir la frase cuando la frase en inglés tiene el sentido de «hay un problema, y quiero que tú seas la persona que lo resuelva».

- Arréglalo
- Corrígelo
- Resuélvelo

Al que, si se quiere ser más despectivo, puédese hacer pronomial y reforzar con un pronombre tónico explícito: *¡resuélvetelo tú!*

Otra versión tal vez más formal podría ser *encárgate de ello*.

Comment: Creo que en esta frase hecha, en general, el verbo `deal` no significa `engargarse de un problema`, sino `tolerar una carga emocional`. Véase por ejemplo la entrada [v. intr. 7 de este diccionario](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deal).

Comment: @rodrigo en este mismo diccionario, puedes ver intr. 3, "to take action with respect to something".

Comment: Cierto, podría significar eso. Pero la frase hecha `Deal with it` se refiere habitualmente a la 7, y seguramente la pregunta también.

Answer (score 3):

In Venezuela:

Cálatela.

OR

Te la calas.

Comment: yo y mis amigos usamos: "Te la pelas", en mexico.

Answer (score 2):

In my country (Northern Spanish) we say sometimes

> Acostúmbrate

I like also the slightly negative and very colloquial

> Te aguantas

Answer (score 2):

Acepta la realidad

Enfréntalo

Acéptalo

Aguántalo

Answer (score 2):

Acabo de ver la expresión en [un vídeo que muestra un brazo robótico](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsF7enQY8uI) sosteniendo un *pen* sobre un *touchpad*, haciendo que el cursor del PC se desplace hasta la casilla del *captcha* que dice "I am not a robot", para seguidamente hacer clic sobre dicha casilla (ironía muy fina). Acto seguido se enfoca al brazo robótico al que le han puesto dos ojitos de pega, aparecen unas gafas pixeladas sobre los ojitos y aparece el texto de la pregunta.

No sé si será muy regional, pero aquí en Andalucía (España) diríamos:

> **¡Ahí lo llevas!**

Me gusta esta frase porque creo que refleja muy bien el original, al tiempo que la complementa. La frase completa sería "ahí lo llevas, ahora apáñatelas" (esta segunda parte sería el "deal with it"), en inglés se omite la primera parte y en la versión en español se omitiría la segunda.

Muy en la línea de esta expresión tendríamos esta otra, que a mí personalmente también me parece que le vendría muy bien al vídeo del robot:

> **¡Chúpate esa!**

Que aunque lo pueda parecer, [no tiene ninguna connotación sexual](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18846/12637) y la puede usar cualquiera.

Comment: Con tu permiso, añado enlace al susodicho vídeo.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv ¡gracias! :-)

Answer (score 1):

En España se emplean estas palabras:

> ¡Aguántate!  *(es una muy buena opción para contextos informales).*
>
> Tendrás que apañarte/Apáñate como puedas

Se interpreta como un desafío:

> "A ver, ahora trata con él/ella"
>
> "Veamos, encáralo/a"
>
> "Ahora afróntalo/a"

Answer (score 1):

> **Arrégleselas**
>
> **Arréglatelas**

**Arreglárselas con...**

**Lidiar con...**

*Coloquial del centro de Colombia:*

> *...Usted verá qué hará con eso...*

*
*Muy coloquial:*

> ...Eso sí... usté' verá...

*

-(Ver qué hacer con...) coloq.

-(Mirar qué hacer con...) coloq.

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina tenemos varias acepciones para esta frase, existe una muy coloquial que va así:  "Chúpala!" o la del famoso Diego Maradona "La tenés adentro" (el comentario de terceros que participarán eventualmente de una escena de estas dirían: " Te re educó " o "Te la re aplicó, manéjala"). Otra muy corta sería "Tomá gato".

Comment: "Chúpala" or "la tenés adentro" have way more aggressive connotations than "deal with it". I could say "deal with it" to people I could never say "Chúpala".

Comment: Creo que entiendo el sentido de da a explicar Ismael. Por ejemplo en Chile podemos llegar a decir *tienes que **comértela** no más*, y bajo esta percepción, *chúpala* se entiende como *tragar*, pero no el sentido ordinario, sino en el de aceptación forzosa ante la situación.

Answer (score 1):

En México se diría: soporta, panzona

Answer (score 0):

En situaciones como las que describe *Charlie*, y desmarcándome también de un verbo en imperativo, se puede decir:

> **¡Toma castaña!**

o

> **¡Toma jeroma!**
>           con su versión extendida
>   **Toma jeroma, pastillas de goma.**

o incluso

> **¿Cómo te has *quedao*?**

Answer (score 0):

Otras que aún no dijeron podrían ser ‘**¡Te (re-) cabió!**’ o ‘**¡Te cabe!**’