# ¿Por qué se dice "chúpate esa" cuando replicamos a alguien dejando su argumento en evidencia?

Tags: expresiones

En conversaciones un tanto acaloradas, no es raro oír la expresión *chúpate esa*:

> — Ayer te oí volver a casa muy tarde. ¿No estarías pendoneando otra vez?
>   — Pues no, venía de estudiar en la biblioteca. ¡**Chúpate esa**!

Es decir, al contrarrestar un argumento, alguien usa *chúpate esa* para vanagloriarse de haber dejado al otro en mala posición. También se podría usar *¡toma!* o alguna otra.

Me parece muy gráfico el uso de la expresión: has dicho algo y te toca tragártelo de alguna forma, aunque sea metafóricamente. De todos modos, me parece curioso que se use *chupar* como verbo. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

No sea usa muchísimo, pero sí cada vez más:

[image]

Comment: Primera entrada en [el CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=ch%FApate+esa&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000): Benito Pérez Galdós en 1878.

Comment: Para mí la frase tiene el sentido que tú le has dado pero he leído aquí otra cosa: http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/biblioteca_fraseologica/n1_cantera/diversidad_05.htm y además aparece también _¡Chúpate esa mandarina!_ lo de la mandarina no lo había oído nunca.

Comment: @blonfu precisamente leyendo esta página caí en esta expresión y se me ocurrió preguntarlo.

Comment: Actualización: es más antigua. [Entradas](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=*pate+esa&autor=&titulo=&ano1=1000&ano2=1900&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) en el CORDE desde 1764. Sigo buscando.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo buena idea, la de buscar en el CORDE. Buscando _*pate es*_ me salen los mismos resultados. Es curioso, pues no se ven demasiadas entradas pese a ser una expresión relativamente común (ser poco formal supongo que la penaliza en listados así).

Comment: @fedorqi ¿Es como lo del inglés "Put _that_ in your pipe and smoke it!", no?

Comment: @Conrado no conocía la expresión inglesa, pero viendo [su explicación](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_that_in_your_pipe_and_smoke_it) me da la sensación de que sí, son absolutamente equivalentes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a dar una opinión sobre el posible origen de la expresión.

> *De la misma nación hubo otra señalada matrona casada con uno de los reyes de Inglaterra, el cual en una guerra en que se halló contra los sirios, como fuese herido en un brazo con cierta hierba, y vuelto a su tierra no hallase remedio para su salud, sino uno, y era que alguno le chupase aquella materia y ponzoña mezclada, no quería dejarse chupar la herida, viendo que había peligro muy peligroso de perder la vida quien tal emprendiese hacer. Pero la reina, viendo esto, disimuló luego de presente, y después como a la noche le vio que dormía, le desató la herida y comenzósela a chupar y escupir aquella materia.*
>
> Juan Justiniano, "Instrucción de la mujer cristiana, de J.L. Vives", España (1528)

Desde hace siglos se ha venido usando la expresión "chuparse las heridas" para indicar que es una posible forma de sanarlas. En el siglo XVI se referían sobre todo a posibles escozores o urticarias provocadas por determinadas hierbas ponzoñosas o venenosas. [Aquí](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=chupa*%20dist%2F2%20herida&autor=&titulo=&ano1=1000&ano2=1700&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) algunas entradas en el CORDE.

Teniendo en cuenta que la expresión se usa cuando se ha dicho algo que puede haber provocado un escozor o herida figurada en la otra persona (expresión "usada como comentario irónico a algo que produce incomodidad o fastidio a alguien", [según la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=94gRaCx#8gKShT8)), no es descabellado pensar que la expresión se use para indicar a la otra persona que se puede ir chupando la herida (esa) si quiere que se cure.

Comment: Resulta una explicación razonable - como siempre, ¡gracias por aportar luz!