# ¿Cuál sería la mejor palabra en español para designar a una persona "creepy"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, españa, adjetivos

Tengo un compañero que suele hablar usando muchos anglicismos, algo que cada día es más común sobre todo en la gente joven que juega a videojuegos *online*, cuyo lenguaje se inunda de expresiones prestadas.

Hoy llega y nos enseña una foto jocosa y nos dice que "la foto es [to'](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19504/12637) creepy". La imagen mostraba a dos personas, y estaba trucada para ponerle a uno la cara del otro y viceversa.

El término "creepy" aplicado a personas significa, [según el Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/creepy), *annoyingly unpleasant*. En español se usan expresiones como *espeluznante, terrorífico, horripilante*, pero me parecen demasiado fuertes para designar a una foto que simplemente *da mal rollo*.

Así que eso es lo que ando buscando: una palabra que exprese que algo "da mal rollo" pero que sea algo más formal, sin llegar al extremo de "terrorífico", y que se pueda usar en ejemplos que traduzcan expresiones como "a creepy old man". ¿Cuál podría ser esa palabra?

<sub>Nota: pregunta orientada al español de España, pero estaré encantado de oír versiones de otras regiones, incluso coloquiales.</sub>

Comment: The term _horripilante_ certainly covers one meaning well especially in the sense of giving you that feeling of hairs on end or making you shiver slightly.

Comment: En este caso, personalmente, lo traduciría como grima ("un viejo grimoso", en el caso del ejemplo)

Comment: `cada día es más común sobre todo en la gente joven que juega a videojuegos **online**` LOL

Comment: @mgarciaisaia no lo he dicho como algo despectivo. El juego online te acerca a personas de todo el mundo y hace que aprendas más inglés, hasta el punto de darte cuenta de que hay palabras y expresiones inglesas que encajan mejor con lo que se quiere decir, y las usan. Y eso es bueno. Me imagino un mundo futuro en el que todos hablemos una amalgama de los principales idiomas del mundo. Pero por ahora nuestro objeto de estudio es el idioma español puro y duro, así que en ello estamos. :)

Comment: No, no, lo se. Solamente me causó gracia que, en una pregunta en la que da la sensación de que intentaste mantenerte sin usar anglicismos, se haya colado _online_ :)

Comment: @mgarciaisaia ah, bien, no te había entendido. Pues anda que si lees la respuesta que acabo de dar a [otra pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19514/12637)... :D

Comment: Diría yo 'escalofriante' como para 'creepy', pero tiene un sentido más como 'horriplante'.

Comment: No os olvidéis que creepy es **argot** (informal) en inglés.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como bien ha dicho @Juansero29, hay muchas posibles traducciones para *creepy*, dependiendo del contexto.

A mí personalmente me gusta tu ejemplo de `que da (muy) mal rollo`, o incluso `que da (mucho) yuyu` o simplemente `que es (muy) chungo`, aunque todos estos son ejemplos de lenguaje informal (y no sé si tienen sentido fuera de España)...

Si quieres algo más formal, ¿qué tal **`siniestro`**?

Yo creo que es suficientemente formal, pero sin llegar a ser pedante o exagerado, y quedaría bastante bien con tus ejemplos de la foto y del señor mayor...

Comment: ¡Bien por [dar yuyu](http://www.1de3.es/2007/04/15/dar-yuyu/)! En España se usa bastante, no sé si en otras regiones también.

Comment: +1 por "siniestro", me mola.

Comment: siniestro is sinister in English. RIght meaning, wrong register.

Answer (score 7):

Pongo yo mismo una posible respuesta que se nos ha ocurrido hoy, que no implica que vaya a ser la acertada ya que hay otras opciones muy buenas.

¿Qué os parece "**inquietante**"?

Según el diccionario, "[inquietar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LijUvTR)" es "quitar el sosiego, turbar la quietud". Aunque no sé si cumple exactamente con los requisitos de *annoyingly unpleasant* (que desagrada de una forma molesta).

Así, tendríamos "un viejo inquietante", o "una foto inquietante".

Y ya por pura curiosidad, usando [el DIRAE](http://dirae.es) (y hablando de que algo moleste y desagrade a partes iguales) he encontrado:

> **[agraz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=18rnpQN)**
>
> De *agro<sup>2</sup>*.
>
> 2. adj. Desagradable, molesto.

¿Se podría decir que un viejo "es agraz"? ¿O una foto?

Comment: A mí me suena bien también! Sí que creo personalmente que, como apuntas tú mismo, `inquietante` tiene un matiz ligeramente menos negativo que otras sugerencias. Algo puede ser inquietante en el sentido de que te saca de la monotonía, que es excitante o misterioso, pero de una forma no tan negativa como `siniestro`, y mucho menos que `terrorífico` desde luego...

Comment: @MikO estoy de acuerdo contigo, de momento tu opción de "siniestro" creo que es la que mejor encaja.

Comment: inquietante is disquieting or uncanny. creepy is slang.

Answer (score 6):

El anglicismo '*creepy*' es usado ahora como adjetivo para designar una amplía gama de sentimientos, situaciones, personas, objetos, entre otros. Muchas veces '*creepy*' puede significar dos palabras distintas en español. Por ejemplo, en la expresión que usaste '*a creepy old man*' podría significar "Un viejo rarísimo" o "Un viejo que da miedo", "Un viejo horripilante". También en algunos países esta denotación podría llegar a significar "Viejo morboso" o "Viejo verde". Incluso podría designar alguien que se comporta de manera extraña o que es misterioso / introvertido.

Debido a estas múltiples interpretaciones de la palabra, me atrevería a decir que **no hay una sola palabra que traduzca '*creepy*'**. Todo depende del contexto en el que la palabra se utilice y el sentido que le podamos dar con la frase en sí o con la entonación.

A veces, los anglicismos producen un efecto de bola de nieve al ser llevados a otros idiomas haciendo que en las lenguas que acojen el anglicismo la palabra pierda su significado original y empiece a usarse en otros contextos. Este fenómeno es más común cuando se trata de palabras famosas en términos de entretenimiento y su uso en las redes sociales y el internet. Es el caso para palabras como '*creepy*', '*cringe*', '*swag*, entre muchas otras.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ¡y bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Entiendo lo que comentas, la verdad es que a veces el contexto puede inclinar la balanza hacia un sentido u otro. Sin embargo, al igual que "creepy" puede ser una palabra un tanto genérica que en el propio idioma inglés podría ser sustituida por otra más específica, debe de haber en español una palabra también un tanto genérica que produzca la misma sensación que la original. Igual tú tienes razón, pero de momento vamos a seguir buscando. ¡Esperamos que te diviertas aquí!

Comment: En el sentido de *viejo morboso/verde*, otra alternativa válida podría ser *viejo casposo*. Torrente, el ejemplo clásico de la "España casposa", podría definirse como *creepy* o *cringey*.

Answer (score 5):

En este caso, personalmente, lo traduciría como grima ("un viejo grimoso", en el caso del ejemplo)

Según la RAE la definición de grimoso es "que da [grima](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JXutzHi)" que a su vez según la propia RAE quiere decir:

> 1. f. desazón (‖ disgusto).
> 2. f. dentera (‖ sensación desagradable).
> 3. f. Hond. Temor muy intenso.

Tomando como referencia la definición inglesa "annoyingly unpleasant", dada en la pregunta, que se traduciría literalmente como "molestamente desagradable", cuadraría con la de grima como sinónimo de dentera (sensación desagradable).

Comment: ¡Qué buena edición! Muchas gracias y bienvenido a [spanish.se]

Comment: Gracias fedorqui :) la ignorancia de como debía responderse propiamente dicho me llevó a ser tan escueto. Espero que sea útil mi aportación.

Comment: ¡Claro que sí! Lee [tour] y [answer] para el futuro, pero ya has tomado un muy buen camino :)

Answer (score 4):

**Tenebroso**

En la RAE:

> [**tenebroso, sa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZSzYYeh)
>
> Del lat. *tenebrōsus*.
>
> - adj. Oscuro, cubierto de tinieblas.
> - adj. Sombrío, tétrico, negro.
> - adj. Hecho ocultamente y con intenciones perversas.

Comment: ¡No está mal! Algo más fuerte que "siniestro" y tal vez menos que "terrorífico". ¡Gracias por participar, y bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]!

Comment: Gracias. Esta palabra da el matiz que creo la palabra inglesa 'creepy' contiene. Así que la fotografía referida podría ser también  «un tanto tenebrosa» o «muy tenebrosa» para énfasis de la sensación que provoca.

Answer (score 2):

Muchas veces (aunque depende siempre del contexto), cuando veo este adjetivo inglés me sale traducirlo utilizando la expresión "dar repelús".

> #### [repelús](http://dle.rae.es/?w=repel%C3%BAs)
>
> **1.** [m.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25981/12991) Temor indefinido o repugnancia que inspira algo.

Incluso existe, en inglés, la cercana expresión [*to give the creeps*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+the+creeps).

Añado una opción que no ha aparecido y que puede ser útil en según qué contextos:

> #### [repulsivo, va](http://dle.rae.es/?w=repulsivo)
>
> **2.** [adj.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25981/12991) Que causa repulsión.

> #### [repulsión](http://dle.rae.es/?w=repulsi%C3%B3n)
>
> **3.** [f.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25981/12991) Repugnancia, aversión.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que la mejor definición es **siniestro**, porque se puede ser repulsivo, sin tener el sentido de espeluznante; simplemente refiriéndose a alguien asqueroso. Una persona espeluznante, te atemoriza, te inspira pavor; pero alguien siniestro, sobre todo te produce intranquilidad, inquietud porque no sabes lo que esconde, aunque intuye, que es algo malo.

Answer (score 0):

creep = (adj.) perturbador, enervante, repulsivo, obsesivo, raro, extraño, que irrita, que da urticaria, que pone nervioso, que incómoda, desagradable.

creep = (sust.) engendro.

creep = (liter.) Macabro, siniestro, misterioso, espeluznante, escalofriante.

- (p.v.) to creep in = insinuarse
- (p.v.) to creep on = acercarse sigilosamente
- (p.v ) to creep out = escaparse sin ruido, sigilosamente
- (p.v.) to creep back onto = retornar sigilosamente.
- (sex.) to dirty old man = dity auld man = viejo verde, cochino, puerco, puto, chulo.
- (sex.) to have the vibe of dirty depraved, have the vibe of, mala vibra, mala cara, mal aspecto, pinta de degenerado, asqueroso.

(liter.)

- it gives me the creeps = it gives me the shivers = me da repelús, me repugna, me desagrada.

Answer (score -1):

A bote pronto, y compartiendo la misma raiz que *creepy*, tenemos la española [**crápula**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BCIFWX7):

> Del lat. *crapŭla*, y este del gr. κραιπάλη *kraipálē*.
>   1. f. Disipación, libertinaje.
>   2. f. p. us. Embriaguez o borrachera.
>   3. m. Hombre de vida licenciosa.

Comment: If i understand that correctly that is not what creepy means, at least in the UK. As several people have commented in other answers it has several meanings but not any of these three.