# ¿Cómo se podría traducir "sanitize" aplicado al ámbito informático?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

La pregunta de hoy viene acompañada de una tira del gradioso blog [XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/):

[image: Bobby tables]

<sup>[Source](https://xkcd.com/327/)</sup>

En la última viñeta se habla del concepto "to sanitize" aplicado en este caso a las consultas contra bases de datos, para evitar cosas como el *exploit* que hace la madre. Según el [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanitize), "sanitize" en este caso significa:

> To make more acceptable by removing unpleasant or undesired features.

Un compañero mío (sí, el mismo que [la otra vez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19505/12637)) acaba de decirme que si estaba usando un *framework* de acceso a base de datos que me permitiera *sanitizar* las consultas. Así que pregunta al canto: ¿cuál sería el mejor verbo en español que podría ser usado para traducir esa última frase de la viñeta?

Opciones contempladas que no nos convencen:

- Desinfectar
- Purgar
- ¿Limpiar?

Comment: ¿Soy el único a quien esta tira recuerda al fontanero de *El milagro de P. Tinto*, que está todo el rato diciendo *hay que sanear, hay que sanear*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parece que la palabra usada en el mundo de la informática es *sanear* y su sustantivo *saneamiento*:

> [**sanear**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XCL17Zm)
>   De sano y -ear.
>   1. tr. Afianzar o asegurar la reparación o satisfacción del daño que puede sobrevenir.
>   2. tr. Reparar o remediar algo.
>   3. tr. Dar condiciones de salubridad a un terreno, a un edificio, etc., o preservarlos de la humedad y vías de agua.
>   4. tr. Liberar de dificultades económicas una empresa.
>   5. tr. Der. Indemnizar al comprador por la evicción o por el vicio oculto de la cosa vendida.

Aquí yo me quedo con la acepción 3, en cuanto a preparar una consulta (una "query") para que los datos de los usuarios no provoquen desastres.

> [**saneamiento**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XCKnqJV)
>   1. m. Acción y efecto de sanear.
>   2. m. Conjunto de técnicas y sistemas destinados a mejorar las condiciones higiénicas de un edificio, una comunidad o una ciudad.
>   3. m. Sistema de evacuación y tratamiento de los residuos urbanos e industriales de una ciudad.
>   4. m. Conjunto de acciones para mejorar y corregir una situación económica.

Por ejemplo, el lenguaje php, muy susceptible a este tipo de "bromas pesadas", tiene una sección de su documentación llamada [Filtros de saneamiento](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php) (en inglés, [Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)).

Para seguir con los argumentos cuantitativos "de uso", la página XKCD de donde sacaste el chiste tiene una versión en castellano en la que [este chiste](http://es.xkcd.com/strips/exploits-de-una-madre/) se tradujo con *sanear*:

> [image]

Comment: Pues fíjate que yo me quedaba con la acepción 1, que es más orientada precisamente a eso, a prevenir "el daño que puede sobrevenir".

Comment: @CarlosAlejo son bastante parecidas. De todos modos, en el contexto que conozco, del tipo [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) yo veo el esfuerzo de _sanear_ como una preparación, más que una reparación (que en muchos casos no es posible, como con el caso del Bobby del chiste). En este sentido, se trata de prevenir que el mal pueda originarse. Pero tú como Scrum Master seguro que tienes una visión más amplia de posibles casuísticas.

Comment: +1. Aparte añado que también existen "sanity checks" donde "sanity" hace más referencia a "cordura" que a "sanear", aunque es cierto que se puede entender la cordura como "salud o limpieza mental..." :-) (por ejemplo, "como _sanity check_, esta consulta te debería devolver 134 filas").

Comment: @Diego ¡bien visto! En un trabajo que tuve le llamaban los _cross checks_, no sé si el significado es el mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Me he encontrado con *sanitize* en el contexto de almacenamiento de datos con dos sentidos hasta cierto punto parecidos:

- Borrar datos sensibles de un archivo, dispositivo o sistema. Se realiza con el fin de poder desclasificar por completo los datos o reducir a un menor nivel de seguridad.
- Proceso para eliminar información de los soportes de tal forma que la recuperación de los datos no sea posible. Incluye la eliminación de todas las etiquetas, marcas y registros de actividad.

En el primero quedan datos, en el segundo desaparece todo. Ambos casos los he traducido como **desinfectar**.

Answer (score 0):

El término que yo he usado en mi carrera en Informática en México es *Depurar*. Ejemplo: Esos datos no han sido depurados.

Cuando trabajaba en Calzado Canadá, el proceso de datos de Producción consistía en 3 fases: Captura, Depuración, y Proceso. La fase de Depuración era una especie de proceso híbrido por el cual los datos capturados se verificaban contra otras bases de datos antes de incorporarse a las bases definitivas, ya que estos procesos se hacian en tiempo real, y la fase de Depuración tenia por objetivo reducir en la medida de lo posible la contaminación de las bases principales.

Comment: Depurar tiene más el significado de verificar o validar. *Sanitice* tiene el sentido de sanear, limpiar (un quirófano de microbios y bacterias).